What is this set? Unknown baire generic set
I'm interested in the set given in this question. For clarity, set
$$S_{\epsilon} = \cup_{j = 1}^{\infty} \left( q_j + \frac{\epsilon}{2^j}, q_j -  \frac{\epsilon}{2^j}\right)$$
where $\\{q_j\\}$ is an enumeration of the rationals. Consider
$$S = \cap_{k = 1}^{\infty} (S_{1/k} \backslash \{q_k\}) $$
Since each $S_{1/k} \backslash \{q_k\} $ is open and dense, the Baire category theorem gives that $S$ must be baire generic in $\mathbb{R}$, and hence dense. However, $S$ cannot contain any rational number - so what is this set? Moreover, does it depend on the enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$?
I have some feeling that this is related to Liouville numbers, but lack any references.

See Oxtoby, Measure NS Category, Springer-Verlag, chapter 1.

$S$ is a zero-measure dense $G_\delta$ that does not contain any rational number. It is not clear what you are asking when you wrote "- so what is this set?"
